# Can't connect to Samsung Gear 360 from command line

Tags: bash, usb, mtp

I'm simply trying to access the videos on my Samsung Gear 360 from a Linux(Ubuntu) desktop.
I'm using the following mtp packages and have confirmed the Camera is recognized as an MTP device. The following DOES work with an LGE 360 camera.

```
sudo apt-get install libmtp-dev mtp-tools mtpfs
```

However when I try and connect via the following command

```
mtp-files > file_list.txt
```

I successfully create the text file but it only contains

```
libmtp version: 1.1.10

mtp-files: Successfully connected
```

and get the following command line errors

```
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
LIBMTP PANIC: failed to open session on second attempt
Unable to open raw device 0
```

Anyone have any luck connecting to a Samsung gear 360 from the command line?

Comment: Is the device unlocked? Is it auto-locking? If so, have you tried disabling auto-locking? Related:https://sourceforge.net/p/libmtp/code/ci/HEAD/tree/README

Comment: Wow, great troubleshooting list. In my case I'm guessing vendor is prioritizing security and privacy over ease-of-use. Have no idea though how to 'unlock' the camera.

Comment: I think you may be correct in your assumptions. I don't have your device but I would look under settings, for MTP, PTP or USB and see what I could find there...